# PerformanceProgressBar loses its dots

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, progress-bar

I'm using PerformanceProgressBar from WP toolkit on some of my pages, strangely as I tap on more links in my application and go through the navigation, the number of dots in the Progress Bar keep decreasing (Minimum two dots).
This is happening only on my HTC HD7 Windows Phone Mango device , it works fine on my Lumia 920 WP8

Not sure if this is part of the implementation and related to the performance or I did something wrong !

Comment: I just noticed that sometimes it shows only one dot on my Lumia 920 ,but when I navigate to a different page with no data binding or collections then go back to the main page and again open a page with large collections and data binding it shows 4-5 dots , I can't figure out what the problem is.